# Show $\ln(2)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Show $$\ln(2)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$

We know que if $|z|<1$.

$$\ln(1-z)=-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(z)^{n}}{n}$$

But $z=-1$ for our case and I wouldn't meet the condition $|z|<1$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146471/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2086393/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cdfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Bn%7D%20%3D%20%5Clog%202%24&p=1)

Comment: "$z=-1$...wouldn't meet the condition $|z|<1$".  It does not have to.  All that is needed is convergence, which could happen at some (though not all) unit-sized values of $z$.